# DOM4J Document: read an ISO-8859-1 xml

Tags: java, xml, iso-8859-1, dom4j, xml-encoding

I need to read an xml file that is encoded in ISO-8859-1.

I'm using:

```
Document document = reader.read(new File(sourceFile));
document.setXMLEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

I'm getting a `"cannot find symbol"` error for `setXMLEncoding`.  This seems like it should be a simple thing, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`setXMLEncoding`](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Document.html#setXMLEncoding%28java.lang.String%29) is available since `dom4j` 1.6. I guess you're using an older version.

Anyway, as the javadoc says:

> Sets the encoding of this document as it will appear in the XML
>   declaration part of the document.

you should use that method if you're writing an xml. 
I guess you're reading an existing file, so if it's `ISO-8859-1` encoded and its prolog contains the same encoding declaration, you shouldn't have any problem, `dom4j` should do everything for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

Comment: I found that dom4j1.6 has a bug, and I needed to add another jar for it to work.